# Eclipse anonymous inner type template

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-templates

When I enter an inner type using fast complete feature of eclipse, it uses some template to generate it.

What I get is seen at left side, what I want is shown at right side of picture. [image: Problem Description Picture]

What I want is to remove empty line and auto-generated method stub thing, how can I manage this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Removing TODO:**  *Window* → *Preferences* → *Java* → *Code Style* → *Code Templates*.

  (Remove `// ${todo} Auto-generated method stub` from *Method body* inside *Code* tree).
- **Removing empty lines:** *Window* → *Preferences* → *Java* → *Formatter* → *Edit* → *Blank Lines* → *Before First Declaration = 0*.

You'll see many options there and you can set it as you wish.

Comment: I think you can just remove the newline in the Class body code template instead of editing the White Space preferences.

Comment: Indeed. But that holds only for classes, if he wants to customize it as he want, he has more flexibility in the `Blank Lines` tab.

Comment: I managed to remove TODO, but stuck at first line, which body should I remove?

Comment: @bluebrain See the second point in my answer, there you should be able to manage new lines (whether should or not they be there)

Comment: ok, I fount it, ty. btw formatter is "Window → Preferences → Java → Code Style" in my eclipse

Comment: I understand that the second option will fix. But how do I format only the anonymous inner class?